# Post's arent displaying

Tags: posts, categories, customization

Im having 2 issues, 
The query is not returning the posts
My custom post type is supplier-showcase
my custom taxonomy is supplier-category
The category in the taxonomy is supplier-cakes

The other issue is, when I do get it to display all Taxonom post (so all the ones in the categories under Supplier Category) Im getting 300 posts per page rather than 25

```
<div class="gridcontainer">


<?php
// Grid Parameters
$counter = 1; // Start the counter
$grids = 5; // Grids per row
$titlelength = 20; // Length of the post titles shown below the thumbnails
// The Query


         $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'supplier-showcase',
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'supplier-category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'supplier-cakes'
                            )
                            )
                        );

                    $query = new WP_Query($args); 
// The Loop
if (have_posts()) :


        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
// Show all columns except the right hand side column
if($counter != $grids) :
?>
<div class="griditemleft">
    <div class="postimage">
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>


 <a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" ><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"   /></a>
    </div><!-- .postimage -->
    <h2 class="postimage-title">

title is <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h2><?php endif; ?>
    <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="lightbox-by-id lightbox-content lightbox-white mfp-hide" style="max-width:600px ;padding:20px">

<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="200px" height="200px"   /> <br>
</div>
</div><!-- .griditemleft -->
<?php
// Show the right hand side column
elseif($counter == $grids) :
?>
<div class="griditemright">
    <div class="postimage">
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>


 <a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" ><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"   /></a>
    </div><!-- .postimage -->
    <h2 class="postimage-title">

title is <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h2><?php endif; ?>
    <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="lightbox-by-id lightbox-content lightbox-white mfp-hide" style="max-width:600px ;padding:20px">

<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="200px" height="200px"   /> <br>
</div></div><!-- .griditemright -->

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php
$counter = 0;
endif;
$counter++;
endwhile;

    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>

</div><!-- .gridcontainer -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can anyone see what Im missing here please.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I had a quick look, copied your code and changed two things: `if (have_posts()) :` changed to `if ($query->have_posts()) :`. Than in your tax_query you forgot the commas ... `'tax_query' => array(
                         array(
                             'taxonomy' => 'supplier-category',
                             'field' => 'slug',
                             'terms' => 'supplier-cakes'
                             ),
                            ),` Please see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. However Im still not getting anything up. I put in what you found, and still nothing. There is no script error in terms of error 500 coming back. It just shows the header and footer and thats it. but Like I said, If I just have it bring the post type and all custom categories it works. Just not when selecting an actual category. For example "supplier-cakes"

Comment: You said if you remove the tax query than posts will show, maybe something is wrong in your tax_query. Maybe try using ID´s instead of slugs. Anyway, I looked again at your code and will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recreated your setup.
I created a post-type called "supplier-showcase".
I created a taxonomy called "supplier-category", and added a term with the slug "supplier-cakes".
Added some posts with and without the term "supplier-cakes".

Than I copied your code, inserted it in a simple page template, fixed the things I already mentioned, and reindented the code (for my readability).
**This is working without any problems:**

```
<div class="gridcontainer">

<?php
// Grid Parameters
$counter = 1; // Start the counter
$grids = 5; // Grids per row
$titlelength = 20; // Length of the post titles shown below the thumbnails

// The Query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'supplier-showcase',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'supplier-category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'supplier-cakes'
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        // Show all columns except the right hand side column
        if($counter != $grids) : ?>

            <div class="griditemleft">

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <div class="postimage">
                        <a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" ><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"   /></a>
                    </div><!-- .postimage -->
                <?php endif; ?>

                <h2 class="postimage-title">
                    title is <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>

                <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="lightbox-by-id lightbox-content lightbox-white mfp-hide" style="max-width:600px ;padding:20px">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="200px" height="200px"   /> <br>
                </div>

            </div><!-- .griditemleft -->

        <?php
        // Show the right hand side column
        elseif($counter == $grids) : ?>

            <div class="griditemright">

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <div class="postimage">
                        <a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" ><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"   /></a>
                    </div><!-- .postimage -->
                <?php endif; ?>

                <h2 class="postimage-title">
                    title is <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>

                <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="lightbox-by-id lightbox-content lightbox-white mfp-hide" style="max-width:600px ;padding:20px">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="200px" height="200px"   /> <br>
                </div>

            </div><!-- .griditemright -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php $counter = 0;

        endif;

    $counter++;

    endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div><!-- .gridcontainer -->
```

---

You also have some problematic if statements in your code like this (see where if starts and ends), which doesnt make sense:

```
<div class="postimage">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" ><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"   /></a>
        </div><!-- .postimage -->

        <h2 class="postimage-title">
            title is <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

You said in your comment that if you remove the tax_query to just show all custom posts, than this is working. So look into the tax_query to see if you got your slugs right. You can also try using term ID´s instead of slugs.